# Get all objects with a specific member value from a list of objects

Tags: c++, sorting, search, std

From a vector

```
std::vector<S> structures;
```

containing structures of the type

```
struct S {
    double x;
    double y;
    double weight;
};
```

I want to repeatedly get all the structs with a specific weight, i.e. I want to execute the following pseudocode:

```
do 1000 times:
   weight = GetASpecificWeight()
   MatchingStructures = structures.GetAllStructuresWithWeight(weight)
```

To do this efficiently, I want to sort the `structures`vector and do a binary search in each iteration.

How can I implement this using std:: code?

Comment: The standard library has a function by the name `std::sort`, that does what you need. Have you tried it? PS. If getting the weight involves calculating the value, do realize that exact equality comparison of floating point values is  meaningless.

Comment: `std::sort` once, then multiple `std::equal_range`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting the vector can be done using [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and finding the range of elements that have the specified weight can be done with [`std::equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range).

However, as Daniel pointed out in the comment, it is likely that `getASpecificWeight()` returns a double and not a `Structure`, so in order to call `equal_range` we either need to create a dummy `Structure` or a function object that compares `double`s to `Structures` with the desired semantics. A single lambda doesn't work because the binary search needs to be able to compare `Structure`s to weights both ways.

### Alternative 1:  Using a dummy Structure

So first, lets create a dummy `Structure`, since this is less code.

In total, it might look something like this

```
auto sort_structure_by_weight_asc = [](Structure const& s1, Structure const& s2) {
    return s1.weight < s2.weight;
};

std::sort(structures.begin(), structures.end(),
          sort_structure_by_weight_asc);

for (auto i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    auto weight = GetASpecificWeight();
  
    auto const dummy_structure = Strucutre{0.0, 0.0, weight};  
    auto range = std::equal_range(structures.cbegin(), structures.cend(),
                                  dummy_structure, sort_structure_by_weight_asc);

    if (range.first != structures.cend() && range.second != structures.cbegin()) {
       // do whatever you want here
       // if the `if`-condition isn't satisfied, no structure
       // had weight `weight`.
    }
}
```

If you need to modify the elements in the `structures` vector, you can replace `cbegin` and `cend` in the call to `std::equal_range` and the `if`-condition by `begin`/`end` respectively.

### Alternative 2: Handcrafted function object

However, I personally don't think creating the dummy struct is very clean, so lets see how a custom function object would improve the code.

The function object itself can be defined as

```
struct ComparatorStructureToWeightAsc {
    bool operator()(Structure const& s, double weight) const {
        return s.weight < weight;
    }

    bool operator()(double weight, Structure const& s) const {
        return weight < s.weight;
    }
};
```

Then the code would look like this:

```
std::sort(structures.begin(), structures.end(),
          [](auto const& s1, auto const& s2) { return s1.weight < s2.weight; });

for (auto i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    auto weight = GetASpecificWeight();
   
    auto range = std::equal_range(structures.cbegin(), structures.cend(),
                                  weight, ComparatorStructureToWeightAsc);

    if (range.first != structures.cend() && range.second != structures.cbegin()) {
       // do whatever you want here
       // if the `if`-condition isn't satisfied, no structure
       // had weight `weight`.
    }
}
```

### Alternative 3: Using Boost.Functional/OverloadedFunction

As you can see I'm bad at naming things, so having to name the function object used to compare Structures to weights is kind of awkward, in particular if it only used in this single place. If you have access to Boost, in particular to [Boost.Functional/OverloadedFunction](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/functional/overloaded_function/doc/html/index.html), you can use two lambdas instead of the handcrafted function object.

The code then looks like this:

```
std::sort(structures.begin(), structures.end(),
          [](auto const& s1, auto const& s2) { return s1.weight < s2.weight; });

for (auto i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    auto weight = GetASpecificWeight();
   
    auto range = std::equal_range(structures.cbegin(), structures.cend(), weight, 
                                  boost::make_overloaded_function(
                                    [](Structure const& s, double weight) { return s.weight < weight; },
                                    [](double weight, Structure const& s) { return weight < s.weight; }));

    if (range.first != structures.cend() && range.second != structures.cbegin()) {
       // do whatever you want here
       // if the `if`-condition isn't satisfied, no structure
       // had weight `weight`.
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't quite right as presumably `GetASpecificWeight` returns a `double` rather than an `S`. You need to modify the comparator.

Comment: @Daniel True, i fixed that.

Comment: Sorry for beeing too unspecific: You can assume that GetASpecificWeight() returns a double, which is exactly equal to at least one of the structure weights.

Comment: @user1934212 All three versions above work when `GetASpecificWeight` returns a double. Daniels comment refers to a previous version of this answer where I had assumed it returns a Structure, which - given its name - should've been obvious.

Comment: @user1934212 The single lambda doesn't work because the comparator passed to `std::equal_range` needs to be callable both with arguments `Structure, double` and `double, Structure` since the binary search will need to compare both ways. I think the Boost version shows the problem best because it defines both lambdas required.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. But wouldn't it be possible to use a simple lambda expression in std::equal_range(... )  and capture the specific weight to compare it with each structures weight?

Comment: @user1934212 No, `equal_range` expects the comparator to be a binary predicate, so capturing the weight doesn't help.

Comment: @Corristo For alternative 2, I would add another overload taking two `Structure`'s and then pass `ComparatorStructureToWeightAsc` to `std::sort`. Then all the comparison logic is in one place.